# Unable to delete environment variable

Tags: google-apps-script

When you delete the variable and save the properties, when you open it again it remains there.
I already looked in the source code and there is no declaration of it.

Project properties[image]

Comment: How did you delete it?

Comment: that happens to me from time to time, I just click run function, it errors out, than fixes itself

Answer (score 1):

#### This might be a bug.

I can reproduce this behaviour. It seems like script properties cannot be removed through the UI dialog (it’s not only that they still show up in the UI, but that they still exist and can be found by the script).

I have reported this in Issue Tracker:

- [Script properties cannot be deleted via UI](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173495423)

Anyone affected by this issue, please consider clicking the star on the top-left in order to keep track of this and to help prioritizing it.